# How to set a variable in a powershell command

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to declare and set a variable in a powershell command. Is that possible?

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
"$name" = "I219" | Get-NetAdapter | where Name -Match "$name"
```

Is this possible or can this only be done in a .ps script?

Comment: Starting with PSv3 the variant without [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) scriptblock is possible, just the first `|` should be a `;` and the double quotes enclosing variable name for output are possible but not neccessary on assigning a variable they are illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily by just hitting enter in the console after declaring your variable:

```
$name = "I219" # now hit enter
```

To access the variable, type it in the console and hit enter again:

```
$name # hit enter => returns I219
```

Now use it with your command:

```
Get-NetAdapter | where { $_.Name -Match $name }
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$name = "I219"; Get-NetAdapter | where { $_.Name -Match $name }
```